# Blacked-out interface rotation when using second UIWindow with rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

(iOS 7.0.3, Xcode 5.0.1)

I have a second UIWindow in my app used to display a custom magnifier above the status bar. However, once I set the rootViewController of this window (for interface rotation & some other stuff), the main window goes black during the interface rotation animation.

To reproduce: create single view iOS application and add the following to the main UIViewController.

```
// To @interface:
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *secondWindow;
// In viewDidLoad:
self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.secondWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add another answer, because I have found a workaround that actually works. Set the window's background color, as well as the view controller's view's background color to a color with an alpha of 0. Do not use `clearColor`, but rather use something like `greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];` It works.

Comment: @Andy Not in my experience. If the view controller's view has a `clearColor` background view, on rotation the background turns black.

Comment: I have rootViewController.view.backgroundColor not even set to anything (nil) and UIWindow.backgroundColor = clearColor. All good.

Comment: Setting `window.backgroundColor` as clear color works for me.

Comment: Clear color worked for me when creating the viewcontroller for the window programmatically, but not by instantiating it from a Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

According to an Apple engineer on the dev forums, this is expected due to the window adding a black background to avoid things behind it to be seen (i.e. behind the main window normally). I opened and issue with the Apple bug tracker, #15398141.

Nevertheless, I worked around the issue by hiding the window in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and unhiding it in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, which luckily is not a big deal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, and there are many radars open for it. Best solution so far for me is to add a view as a subview to the window, and manage rotation yourself. This works well.

Comment: Yeah that's also a good approach. Note that you will also not be able to use iOS 7's UIViewController based status bar appearance, as it will query the second UIWindow (even without rootViewController set).

Answer (score 0):

Make `window.opaque = No` whose default value is YES. In my case it solved the problem.