# Show UIAlertController over keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ios9, uialertcontroller

In iOS 8 and lower show a `UIActionSheet` when keyboard is presented will present the action sheet over the keyboard. With iOS 9 this is no longer the case.

In my app we have a chat functionality and want the show a action over the keyboard. We used to use `UIActionSheet` which worked fine until iOS 8. In iOS 9 the action sheet is present behind the keyboard. I've tried both `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertController`.

What we want is a action sheet like in messages.app
[image: Action sheet in messages app.]

I've tried placing the action sheet in it own window and overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder` which just made the keyboard disappear.

Comment: Are you sure about `UIAlertController`? I had same problem in my app with `UIActionSheet` in iOS9 but when I switched to `UIAlertController` problem gone.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But it does seem to only happen when you are using a it when the keyboards is presente as part of an views `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KEEP keyboard ON when UIAlertcontroller is presented in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564710/keep-keyboard-on-when-uialertcontroller-is-presented-in-swift)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have implemented exactly this in our app. The trick is to have the alert controller appear on a different window. This is how the `UIActionSheet` implementation does it, and works great on iOS 8, but on 9, Apple has moved the keyboard implementation to a window which has a very high window level (10000000). The fix is to give your alert window an even higher window level (as a custom double value, not using the provided constants).

When using a custom window which will have transparency, make sure to read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260717/983912), regarding background color, to prevent window becoming black during rotation transitions.

```
_alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
_alertWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
_alertWindow.windowLevel = 10000001;
_alertWindow.hidden = NO;
_alertWindow.tintColor = [[UIWindow valueForKey:@"keyWindow"] tintColor];

__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    weakSelf.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    weakSelf.alertWindow = nil;
}]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Test" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    weakSelf.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    weakSelf.alertWindow = nil;
}]];

[_alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried everything, but the this high window level.

Comment: @rckoenes It's really annoying. If you run an SDK8 app, it has a low window level so `UIActionSheet` works well. But if the app uses SDK9, it goes to the sky. It's a conspiracy to get you to use `UIAlertController`. `;-)`

Comment: I'm even using `UIAlertController` but even that did not work and was showing nicely behind the keyboard :S

Comment: @rckoenes One more thing. If you support rotation, make sure to give the window's root controller some color (different than `clearColor`) with an alpha of 0, or on rotation, it will appear black. #uiwindowhacks

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: More hacks. If you want to implement something similar to iOS' messages app's action sheet, with an image picker, you can set a `contentViewController` to alert controllers.

Comment: thank you, such a simple solution and good for a while at least, until that value changes again. ;)

Comment: @Leo How'd you discover this value? May the value be discovered at runtime?

Comment: @Travis Unfortunately, not without using private API. Apple split the keyboard into two windows, and the high keyboard window is not accessible without either using the debugger or using private API.

Comment: @LeoNatan Don't you think it's enough to grab the current top window and present the VC inside that? `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows` is ordered by windowLevel.
 See this answer and my explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564710/keep-keyboard-on-when-uialertcontroller-is-presented-in-swift

Comment: @galambalazs No, because the keyboard is drawn in a window of its own, which is a system window that does not appear under `windows`.

Comment: @LeoNatan The code is working iOS 8 & 9. Did you try it? `<UIRemoteKeyboardWindow>` does appear in the list on iOS 9.

Comment: @galambalazs Interesting. I remember looking for that window and not seeing it there in the past. I figured they did it on purpose to better protect the keyboard, with a possible full XPC keyboard implementation in iOS 10 (hence the "Remote" in the name).

Comment: @galambalazs Still, would not present any controller on a system controller, especially one that is managed by the keyboard.

Comment: @galambalazs Also changed your edit to be more correct. Using the main window is not always correct, especially if the application is managing more than one windows. Taking the key window's tint color is more accurate.

Comment: Isn't it `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` that you meant?

Comment: From experience, `+[UIWindow keyWindow]` is more accurate at some edge cases. I just use that.

Comment: Can any one confirm whether this still works for iOS 9.3.5 and iOS 10? I found the maximum of windowLevel you can set is 10000000.

Comment: @sabalaba Please do not modify my answers without first understanding why it is written the way it is written.

Comment: @LeoNatan 1) `[UIWindow valueForKey:@"keyWindow"]` is relying on a class method that is only declared in the runtime headers, and is private API usage for getting the tint color---`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` works just fine without using a private API. 2) What's your reason for accessing the alertWindow variable later? 3) A minor point, but assuming you do have a reason for accessing your alertWindow later, you have inconsistent accessor usage, you use an ivar outside the block and then in the block you use setters (either synthesized with a property or otherwise).

Comment: @Jerome What happens on 10.3?

Comment: @Leo Natan, UIAlertController will under keyboard still.

Comment: Sounds like incorrect setting for the window level. What is the keyboard window level in 10.3?

Answer (score 9):

The answer supplied by Leo is broken as of iOS 11, because Apple now prevents you from setting a windowLevel above `10000000`. A fix is to implement a custom UIWindow and override the `windowLevel` receiver:

```
@interface TopWindow : UIWindow @end

@implementation TopWindow
- (UIWindowLevel) windowLevel {
    return 20000000.000;
}
@end

// usage:
UIWindow* w = [[TopWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
w.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
w.hidden = NO;

[w.rootViewController presentViewController:yourActionSheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This approach should be backwards compatible, but haven't tested all known versions. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 5):

Based on Leo Natan's answer, I've created a Swift extension for presenting an alert sheet over the keyboard.

In my brief testing, the alertWindow is deallocated after the alert is dismissed, I believe because there's no strong reference to it outside of the alert. This means there's no need to hide or deallocate it in your UIAlertActions.

```
extension UIAlertController {

    func presentOverKeyboard(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        // If you need a white/hidden/other status bar, use an appropriate VC.
        // You may not need a custom class, and you can just use UIViewController()
        alertWindow.rootViewController = whiteStatusBarVC()

        alertWindow.windowLevel = 10000001
        alertWindow.hidden = false

        // Set to a tint if you'd like
        alertWindow.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        alertWindow.rootViewController?.presentViewController(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
}

private class whiteStatusBarVC: UIViewController {
    private override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one way to do. I'm using a lot of UIAlertController throughout the app. So, I don't want to deallocate in each handler. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

use UIAlertController instead of UIActionSheet

Comment: That does not work in iOS9, it will still be behind the keyboard.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.