# UIActionSheet behind keyboard bug

Tags: ios9, uiactionsheet

I have problem with running app on iPhone simulator with iOS 9. My app build target is iOS 7.1 and it works fine with iOS 8.

I have attachment button and it is available for user even if keyboard is present. When user push button I present `UIActionSheet` with some actions via `showInView:` method and target view is current view controller's view.

I see that action sheet is behind keyboard frame:

[image]

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647890/show-uialertcontroller-over-keyboard ?

Comment: Looks like so, thank you. But I decided to set my minimal version to iOS 8 and start using `UIAlertController`.